# This is my code and i want to resolve weak warnings in this code

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

this is my code

```
     body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: _firestore.collection('Messages').snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final messages = snapshot.data.docs;
                }
              },
            ),
```

i got the following error :-
"This function has a return type of 'Widget', but doesn't end with a return statement"
i am currently learning flutter so i cant solve this error i know this might be simple error to some of you

i tried to build a streambuilder and i got it right and had no error but i cant solve the warning and weak warnings i am expecting some simple answers that a beginner can understand

Answer (score 1):

so return a widget for this to work. A widget could be a text/container/column/row and etc

```
...
body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: _firestore.collection('Messages').snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final messages = snapshot.data.docs;
                      return Text('Data available: $messages.toString()');//<====return a widget
                }else{
                  return Text('Data not available');//here too
               }
              },
            ),
```